# MySQL- Find records with overlapping period

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-range

I have a table hotel_booking

| reference | start_date | numberOfDays |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 11-08-2021 | 2 |
| DEF | 12-08-2021 | 2 |
| GHI | 13-08-2021 | 3 |
| JKL | 10-08-2021 | 2 |

So the first task I wanted was to get all bookings which has startDate between x and y date which is straight forward query

```
select reference
from hotel_booking
where DATE(start_date) BETWEEN '2021-08-11' AND '2021-08-12'
```

This returns me ABC and DEF which is perfect.

Now I want to check for all booking that have a overlapping period based on numberOfdays

So for example get me all the bookings that are within the period mentioned by startDate and endDate based on numberOfDays

**INPUT:** For example if startDate is 11-08-2021 and endDate is 12-08-2021 then

**Expected Output**: the bookings returned are JKL, ABC and DEF since JKL has booking for 2 days which will overlap with startDate 11-08-2021

Any pointer will be appreciated

Comment: You also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: I have mentioned it.. I will make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not saving end date you need to calculate it as `start_date + interval numberOfDays days` to get the exclusive end date. The date overlap query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE @d2 > start_date AND (start_date + interval numberOfDays day) > @d1
-- In order to check [2021-08-11, 2021-08-12]
-- You will set @d1 and @d2 to 2021-08-11 and 2021-08-13
```

For completeness, here is the inclusive end date version:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE @d2 >= start_date AND (start_date + interval numberOfDays - 1 day) >= @d1
-- In order to check [2021-08-11, 2021-08-12]
-- You will set @d1 and @d2 to 2021-08-11 and 2021-08-12
```

Comment: Thanks.. Is it ok @d2 >= DATE(start_date) and then not changing the end date at all?

Comment: You want to use `[2021-08-11, 2021-08-12]` as-is?

Comment: Yes, the startDate and endDate which would be used for comparison will be those two dates. So when its exact match its only booking with 11 and 12 August (first query) and if its to be checked against all the bookings that are in the interval then your query would come into picture

Comment: See revised answer. Basically both `>` must be changed to `>=` and end date must be start date + (n - 1) days.